# Driver Testing. Could not load test information

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, driver, wdk

Good afternoon folks. Please help me how to solve this problem: every time I start Visual Studio, after installing WDK, I get the following error: "Driver Testing. Could not load test information. Error: Object reference does not point to an object instance." I have already tried a lot of things to solve this problem, for example: reinstalling Visual Studio, reinstalling WDK, reinstalling SDK, tried installing Visual Studio on different drives, and then installing WDK and SDK again - but all my attempts to fix this problem were in vain.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ZtJ.png

Comment: P.S: I just tried to install WDK and VS-studio on a virtual machine - everything works correctly there. It turns out that the problem is in Windows: (Maybe some function is disabled or some component is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following folder exists before you start VS:

C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Testing\Tests